# Python - Print on stdout on a "terminal"

Tags: python, stdout

Before starting, I ask you all to apologize for the question. Maybe it is stupid, but I cannot find a solution.
I am working on a remote machine, and have no idea what type.

My python code, that seems to work, is the one below. The problem is that I am trying to print some outputs on the screen but nothing happens.
I have tried both print and raw_input but nothing happens ... Do you know any other way to do it ?

```
# Set up fields of reply message based on query
def prepareReply():
    global authorReply, authorReplyLen, localConvId, originConvId, blbContentAndUntUnz, linkName

    print "PLOP!"
    raw_input("blabla")

    #print "="*10
```

Thanks !

Comment: Print prints to standard out - the problem must be somewhere else.  Which python version are you using?

Comment: 2.4 Is it possible that the stdout is redidercted somewhere else by default ??

Comment: It is possible to redirect stdout, but I don't think that's done by default.
I've used redirecting for logging to file in circumstances where I didn't have access to stdout.

Comment: So it can be possible to don't have access to stdout...

Comment: did you tried to print anything in python interpreter?

Comment: with python interpreter the print is working fine ! I think that the shell script is redirecting the output somewhere else ... 
I solved the problem printing on files !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect stdout to something that you can read, a file in this case:

```
class PyLogger:

  def __init__(self, source):
    self.file_handle = open('Python_Log.txt', 'a')
    self.source=source
    self.buf = []

  def write(self, data):
    self.buf.append(data)
    if data.endswith('\n'):
      self.file_handle = open('Python_Log.txt', 'a')
      self.file_handle.write('\t' * indent_level)
      self.file_handle.write(self.source + "::" + ''.join(self.buf))
      self.file_handle.close()
      self.buf = []

  def __del__(self):
    if self.buf != []:
      self.file_handle = open('Python_Log.txt', 'a')
      self.file_handle.write('\t' * indent_level)
      self.file_handle.write(self.source + "::" + ''.join(self.buf) + '\n')
      self.file_handle.close()      
    self.file_handle.close()

import sys
sys.stdout = PyLogger('stdout')
sys.stderr = PyLogger('stderr')
```

Comment: Looks like the first open() and close() in write() and __del__() are superfluous.  Or did you want to do self.file_handle.flush()?

Plus, file_handle could really be a class attribute instead of an instance attribute, since it is shared by all instances.

Comment: It's a simple copy-paste of some "code that works" that I haven't thought about in ages, probably originally off the internet somewhere.  You could well be right that much of the code is superfluous.

Answer (score 9):

```
import sys
print "Hi!"
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess, but looking at the wording in your comments indicates that it might be a web server application (hint: more detail on your environment would be helpful). In this case, stdout is probably going somewhere else, at least not to the browser.

How are you actually running that code? Do you type "python myprogram.py" at a shell prompt, or do you hit Reload in your browser?

Comment: the app is running on a server, but not a web server !  It's a particular server processing the transactions...
To run the python program I have to run a shell script that runs my python application ! I have no idea ho the shell script is done ...

Comment: Well, it looks like you're already doing what can be expected from a Python point of view. Since your script is run through some other framework that none of us know anything about, stdout could be redirected anywhere. One thing you could try is: out = open("/dev/tty", "w"); print >>out, "hello world"

Comment: If it runs by some framwework, maybe `return "PLOP!"` will work?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Jori's overloading of sys.stdin and stdout, it is also wise to store the original values of stdin and stdout as follows:

```
import sys
savestreams = sys.stdin, sys.stdout
sys.stdout = PyLogger('stdout')
sys.stderr = PyLogger('stderr')
... 
...
...
sys.stdin, sys.stdout = savestreams
```

Another simple way is:

```
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__
```

if you don't do this, you may find yourself scratching your head as to why your print function no longer sends text to your screen.